# Define input of a variable based on the second variable in a function in R

Tags: r

I want to compute the function of three variables. but third variable depends on second variable. How to assign the third variable based on value of second variable in the function. The code is pasted below.

```
kot <- seq(1,10,length.out=10) # kote
H <- seq(1, 2.1,length.out=10) 


fc= function(H,kot, mu=if(H > 1) {mu =0.1} else { mu=100 }){

  mu*sqrt(2*9.81* (kot-.5))* 2.2* (ifelse((kot-.5)<=H, kot-.5, H))}

z<-outer(H,kot,fc)
```

Comment: Build a function of two variables, and create the third one within your function. The variable mu is temporary, you just need to create it within your function, in order to calculate the final result. Then, just return the final result.

Comment: thanks for the answer. can you edit the code demarsylvain? I tried already no idea so far.

Answer (score 0):

I changed some values, just to show that you can initialize a function with two variables, and build a third one within the function.

```
kot <- 5
H <- 5

outer <- function(H, kot){

  mu <- if(H > 1) {mu = 0.1} else { mu = 100 }
  result <- mu * sqrt(2*9.81* (kot-1))* 2.2* (ifelse((kot-.5)<=H, kot-.5, H))

  return(result)
}

outer(H,kot)
# 8.770305
```

Comment: It seems working with a single values for H but if you have more values on H its ignoring other values of H.  can you try with 10 different values on H and kot?